# cycles renders fire in single image but not in animation. how to fix?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, smoke-simulation, fire

well the thing is: blender renderes my burning text just fine when rendering a single image. but when i render animation the output is black. i checked like 10 different posts on that and nothing helps.

i didnt change anything between the images other than pressing the animation button instead of render.

frame 40 single image render:[image: frame 40 image]

frame 1 animation (yes it shows in frame 1. the text glows.)[image: frame 1 animation]

Answer (score 1):

turns out im just dumb. the animation renders fine, just not the first 3 frames. they are black. i propably just didnt got to frame 1 when testing with single image.

NO NEED TO ANSWER